# Saving Azure ML pipelines in GIT or backup somewhere

Tags: git, pipeline, azure-machine-learning-service

I have 2 queries.

I am creating a Pipelines with Azure ML Designer. Most of them are in Pipeline Draft state. Accidentally the workspace was deleted by one of the Azure tech team.

Will the pipeline draft will also be saved in the Azure Storage account or only the pipelines which are run/submitted only be saved in the Storage container. If the drafts also saved in the storage, could you share the folder where it is stored so that I could use it for restoration.

### Query 2

How to save the Azure ML Pipelines created using the Azure ML designer to be saved in the GIT or some other backup device for future restoration purpose incase of any mishap.

Is it possible to backup pipeline drafts in GIT?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The storage account can be recovered in a few cases within 14 days. While creating the storage account we will mention the retention time, using which we will be using the deleted storage accounts.

Checkout the screenshot for the retention timing allocation.

[image]

[image]

When the pipeline is created, the storage account gets connected to it. It will be an independent entity. Once the data of the pipeline can be lost, but the storage account cannot be lost by default. If the storage account also included in deletion process while deleting pipeline, we can recover in often cases using the time mentioned in this data protection phase.

To clone the model with the GIT use the following procedure

[image]

Get the keys required to cline. Install GIT BASH

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 1234 -C your_email@example.com
```

Clone the Git Repository using

```
git clone git@example.com:GitUser/repo.git
```

**Cloning into 'azureml-example'...**